# Serialize an object in the XML format a WCF endpoint expects

Tags: c#, xml

I need to call a WCF endpoint using an HTTPClient which I have already figured out how to do that. The problem that I have is that I do not know how to code the XML serializer to produce the content string that has worked.

In my code I have the following type:

```
public class MyParameters
{
    public string source { get; set; }
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string secret { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan lockExpirationTime { get; set; }
}
```

And I serialize it like so:

```
var input = new MyParameters
{
    source = "some source",
    key = "some key",
    secret = "some secret",
    lockExpirationTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10)
};

var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyParameters));
var stringwriter = new System.IO.StringWriter();
serializer.Serialize(stringwriter, input);
var xml = stringwriter.ToString();
```

The end result is this xml string:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<MyParameters xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <source>some source</source>
  <key>some key</key>
  <secret>some secret</secret>
  <lockExpirationTime>PT10S</lockExpirationTime>
</MyParameters>
```

But it seems that for the WCF endpoint to be happy and not return a Bad Request result the xml needs to look EXACTLY like this:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <MyParameters xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <source>some source</source>
            <key>some key</key>
            <secret>some secret</secret>
            <lockExpirationTime>PT10S</lockExpirationTime>
        </MyParameters>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

How can I make the serializer give me this result?
I am using .Net Core 3.1

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use a [ServiceReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/how-to-add-update-or-remove-a-wcf-data-service-reference?view=vs-2019)

Comment: @PabloRecalde - Project restrictions we cannot bypass.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/how-to-serialize-an-object-as-a-soap-encoded-xml-stream) article, you would need to decorate your class with soap attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string xml =
                "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\" ?>" + 
                   "<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">" +
                        "<s:Body>" +
                        "</s:Body>" +
                   "</s:Envelope>";
            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XNamespace sNs = doc.Root.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("s");

            XElement body = doc.Descendants(sNs + "Body").FirstOrDefault();
            string source = "some source";
            string key = "some key";
            string secret = "secret";
            string lockExpirationTime = "PT10S";

            XNamespace def = "http://tempuri.org/";
            XElement myParameters = new XElement(def + "MyParameters");
            body.Add(myParameters);

            myParameters.Add(new object[] {
                new XElement(def + "source", source),
                new XElement(def + "key", key),
                new XElement(def + "secret", secret),
                new XElement(def + "lockExpirationTime", lockExpirationTime)
            });


            string xmlStr = doc.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```